# NullReference exception occurs even when the object is not null

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, event-handling

I am new to wpf; I am using an editable comboBox (for search purposes).

When text in the ComboBox is changed, the search result is displayed underneath the datagrid. When any row from the datagrid is selected its values are displayed in textboxes for editing.

When I write something in the combobox, the related row is displayed in the data grid,  but when I click to select a row, the application throws a `nullreference exception`.

My application worked correctly when the dataGrid refreshing logic was behind a button click.

The code for "SelectionChange" Event of the dataGrid is:

```
private void CategoryRowSelected(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ClearForm();

    if(CategoryDataGrid.SelectedItem!=null)
    {
        categoryMember = CategoryDataGrid.SelectedItem as CategoryTbl; // value assigned to the object
        // if (categoryMember != null)
        CategoryName.Text = categoryMember.CategoryName; //Exception thrown on this statement
        CategoryDescription.Text = categoryMember.CategoryDescription;
    }       
}
```

and code for the textChange event of ComboBox is:

```
private void RefreshDataGrid(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CategoryDataGrid.SelectedIndex = -1;           
    //CategoryDataGrid.ItemsSource = RefreshQuery;
    CategoryDataGrid.ItemsSource= Admin.RefreshCategoryDataGrid(NameCombo.Text);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your cast doesn't return null?

Comment: Why are you bothering to use `as` if you're treating it if you had done `(CategoryTbl)CategoryDataGrid.SelectedItem `

Comment: @ConradFrix Maybe the OP prefers getting an `NullReferenceException` instead of an `InvalidCastException` ;)

Comment: @ReedCopsey I think you are giving the OP too much credit.

Comment: Thanks... I got the problem... the type was not converting using the 'as' operator..

Answer (score 5):

```
 CategoryName.Text = categoryMember.CategoryName; //Exception thrown on this statement
```

This can happen for multiple reasons - not just because `categoryMember` is null.  It will also occur if:

- `categoryMember.CategoryName` (the `CategoryName` property itself) returns `null`, as [`TextBox.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and similar properties raise the exception if you set the value to `null`.
- `CategoryName` (the control) is `null`

Also, I see you had a `null` check (for debugging?), but it is commented out.  If `CategoryDataGrid.SelectedItem` is not assignable to `CategoryTbl`, you will receive null in `categoryMember` itself.

Comment: Note: C# has the handy `??`-operator which returns the right argument if the left one is null:  `CategoryName.Text = categoryMember.CategoryName ?? "";`

Comment: Thanks... I got the problem... compiler was not giving an error. there was a type conflict.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to @Reed answer would say, that considering that you say that on `Button` click it works, I immagine `Button` was on the cell. In this case returned type is a different then may happen in `CategoryDataGrid.SelectedItem`. Most probabbly `CategoryDataGrid.SelectedItem` is a **container** of a some type and not directly of a type `CategoryTbl`

Hope this helps.